# WPF Datagrid's OnGeneratingColumn Not firing when using Event Triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to test this at a simple level where I have the following TasksDatagridView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Example.Views.TasksDatagridView" ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:CompleteConverter x:Key="completeConverter" />
        <local:Tasks x:Key="tasks" />
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsTasks" Source="{Binding Path=tasks}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ProjectName"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="myDG" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsTasks}}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="AutoGeneratingColumn">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GenColumns}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In my TasksDatagridView.xaml.cs I tried both setting the datacontext first `this.DataContext = new ViewModels.TaskDgVm()` and then `InitializeComponent()` and vice versa.

In my main window MainWindow.xaml I reference the control like such:

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow" x:Class="Example.Views.MyMainWindowView" ...>
  <Grid>
    <local:TasksDatagridView x:Name="tview" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is a derived example that shows the point so please excuse mispelling. So I am having two issues:

1. In the MainWindow.xaml line where i reference the control: `<local:TasksDatagridView x:Name="tview" />` it says it threw a system.exception, yet the code still compiles and runs fine.
2. AutoGeneratingColumn is not being fired.

Really I am trying to figure out #2 and why this specific event is not firing. Right now I have a simple print in the execute method and when replacing the event name with a simple click or loaded event for the datagrid the command works fine and just about any other event gets fired, which tells me its not something in my viewmodel or delegate command class. Any thoughts on why the autogenerate column event is not working with command? Note I have made sure the event name is not misspelled.

Edit:
After posting question I found a related question here: [MVVM - WPF DataGrid - AutoGeneratingColumn Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881904/mvvm-wpf-datagrid-autogeneratingcolumn-event)
However they use `mvvm-light` toolkit where I am using the expression blend interactivity library. Although the same answer may apply to both questions, they are indeed two separate toolkits.

Comment: Can you please share code for `GenColumns`?

Comment: @Sham its a simple print `"System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Event Fired");` and as mentioned it works with most other events including the loaded event for datagrid

Comment: @arias_JC Did you check console for any binding errors?

Comment: @DipenShah yeah, there are none associated with the control in question. Also, I can call fire AutoGeneratingColumn using code behind just find, it just does not make any sense why it won't work though the interactivity command, and only for that event

Comment: @arias_JC Still can you post those errors as well?

Comment: They do not pertain to the question. I removed all other controls. Just datagrid and no console errors are produced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVVM - WPF DataGrid - AutoGeneratingColumn Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881904/mvvm-wpf-datagrid-autogeneratingcolumn-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on this thread [MVVM - WPF DataGrid - AutoGeneratingColumn Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881904/mvvm-wpf-datagrid-autogeneratingcolumn-event) I believe the visual tree is not getting constructed during some of these events.

But there is an alternative provided that solves the problem while avoiding code behind:

```
public class AutoGeneratingColumnEventToCommandBehaviour
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Command", 
            typeof(ICommand), 
            typeof(AutoGeneratingColumnEventToCommandBehaviour),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                null,
                CommandPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject o, ICommand value)
    {
        o.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static ICommand GetCommand(DependencyObject o)
    {
        return o.GetValue(CommandProperty) as ICommand;
    }

    private static void CommandPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataGrid = d as DataGrid;
        if (dataGrid != null)
        {
            if (e.OldValue != null)
            {
                dataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn -= OnAutoGeneratingColumn;
            }
            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                dataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += OnAutoGeneratingColumn;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        var dependencyObject = sender as DependencyObject;
        if (dependencyObject != null)
        {
            var command = dependencyObject.GetValue(CommandProperty) as ICommand;
            if (command != null && command.CanExecute(e))
            {
                command.Execute(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```