# DataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn problem during init Prism app

Tags: view, datagrid, prism, viewmodel, region

I have problem with AutoGeneratingColumn event in Prism.
One of my View has DataGrid definition:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RegisteredEvents, Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"> 
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="AutoGeneratingColumn">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AutoGeneratingColumnCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

and uses *AutoWireViewModel*. ViewModel of course, is defininig *AutoGeneratingColumnCommand*.
During application init I call *RegisterViewWithRegion*. Application is starting from another view and user has possibility navigate to the view with *DataGrid* by click button. Problem is that before first displaying the view *AutoGeneratingColumnCommand* is not calling. Prism creates View nad ViewModel, sets *DataContext*, *ItemSource* is correct set too and *DataGrid* is filling, but headers are not customizing. After first displaying the view *AutoGeneratingColumn* works fine even user changed view.
I try force refresh *ItemSource* in *OnNavigatedTo* (*INavigationAware* interface), but without success during first navigate event. After it is ok.

How I can resolve this problem? I will be grateful for help.

**Update:** I added handler for *AutoGeneratingColumn* event in code-behind of the view. This handler is calling in effect force refresh *ItemSource* in *OnNavigatedTo*. Command from *EventTrigger* nop.

**Update#2:** I replaced *EventTrigger* with mechanism Command Behavior and now there is not different between this method of handle event and code-behind consumed. I'm not sure, but think that my problem has similar reasons as this: [MVVM - WPF DataGrid - AutoGeneratingColumn Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881904/mvvm-wpf-datagrid-autogeneratingcolumn-event)

Comment: What’s the purpose of `AutoGeneratingColumnCommand` ?

Comment: Customize headers and filter properties to displaying.